# Can't mass assign a nested attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to assign comments which belongs_to answers (and answers has_many comments) and get a can't assign mass protected attributes: answer.

Here is my commentsController

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
 def create
  @answer = Answer.find(params[:answer_id])
  @comment = @answer.comments.new(params[:comment])
  @comment.save
  redirect_to question_path(@answer)
 end
```

end

Here is my answers controller for the page I am using

```
def show
 @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
 @comment = @answer.comments.new(params[:comment])
end
```

My answer model accepts_nested_attributes for comments.

And this is my form,

```
<%= form_for([@answer, @comment]) do |f| %>
  <p>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :comment %>
    <%= f.text_area :answer, :cols => "50", :rows => "30"%>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit "Submit Comment" %>
  </p>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

you should permit params before using it in your comments controller, in rails4 u can do this

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @answer = Answer.find(params[:answer_id])
        @comment = @answer.comments.new(params.require(:comment).permit(:answer))
        @comment.save
        redirect_to question_path(@answer)
    end
end
```

or u can also define a method in comments controller for permitting params as

```
def comment_params
   params.require(:comment).permit(:answer)
end
```

then in your controller create a new record using this function as-

```
@comment = @answer.comments.new(comment_params)
@comment.save
```

as u had said u have nested attrs for comments in answer something like

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end
```

and u are also using attr_accessible so to permit params in nested form u have to do

`attr_accessible :comments_attributes`  along with your answer attrs in your answer.rb

Comment: I've allowed answer to accept nested attributes in comments (which belongs to answer) so why is this an issue? All my fields in comments are also attr_accessible so I'm not sure why the permit would help or even why I can't assign these.

Comment: ok so u are using rails version < 4 or gem nested attributes...which one..? let me update my answer..?

Comment: its actually protected_attributes gem, typos in above comment sorry.

Comment: Rails 3, sorry for not including that! the same structure is working for questions --> answers for me, but not answers --> comments.

Comment: Yea added attr_accessible, this seems like it'll be hard to figure out. Maybe I'll create new models and see what happens.