# Link_to create with parameter before - ForbiddenAttributesError now

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

**What I Want:**

I need in a view a button or a link (it doesn't matter) to the ***create*** action of ***Reservation*** controller and to give it a parameter too.

And resolve the ForbiddenAttributesError that now gives me.

**Here are my model and controller:**

**Reservation model**

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :dinner
end
```

**Reservation controller**

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def show
    @reservations = Reservation.joins(:user).where('dinner_id' => params[:dinner_id]).select("users.*,reservations.*")
    @dinnerid = params[:dinner_id]

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render :json => @reservations }
    end
  end

def create
@reservation = Reservation.new(params[:reservation])
@reservation.user_id = current_user.id

respond_to do |format|
      if @reservation.save
        format.html { redirect_to @reservation, notice: 'Reservation was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @reservation }
      else
        format.html { render :show }
        format.json { render json: @reservation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def reservation_params
    params.require(:reservation).permit(:dinner_id)
  end

end
```

***EDIT***: After the suggestion of @Rahul Singh this is my actual code with relative error:

```
    <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>User id</th>
    <th>Dinner id</th>
    <th>User email</th>
    <th>User name</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  <% @reservations.each do |reservation| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= reservation.id %></td>
        <td><%= reservation.user_id %></td>
        <td><%= reservation.dinner_id %></td>
        <td><%= reservation.user.email %></td>
        <td><%= reservation.user.name %></td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br/>TRY 00a <br/>
<%= form_for(Reservation.new) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field( :dinner_id, :value => @dinnerid.to_s) %>
    <%= f.submit "Join1" %>
<% end %>
<br/> !!!!!!!!!!ERROR : ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

<br/>TRY 00b <br/>
<%= link_to "Join1", reservations_path(dinner_id:@dinnerid.to_s), method: :post %>
<br/> !!!!!!!!!!ERROR : param is missing or the value is empty: reservation
```

I provide a sreenshot for the error :

Error of the form : https://www.dropbox.com/s/i2x1m520ptqdj56/createReservationForm.jpg

Error of the link_to : https://www.dropbox.com/s/8xjwee5oo7q6uhk/createReservationLink_to.jpg

Comment: Can you post the full error of `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`?

Comment: You just have a hidden field and a submit button in your form??

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-yNVqjtfhuIVGIxT3dkQ0FycEE/edit?usp=sharing here Paven.
yes user2675613

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
<%= form_for(Reservation.new) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field( :dinner_id, :value => @dinnerid.to_s) %>
    <%= f.submit "Join1" %>
<% end %>
```

clicking on Join1 button will submit form to ReservationsController create action.

and with link try this

```
<%= link_to "Join1", reservations_path(dinner_id:@dinnerid.to_s), method: :post %>
```

for above to work,add following in your routes.rb

```
resources :reservations
```

Comment: error: "undefined method `reservations_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000003c82050>:0x0000000361abb8>" does it means that I have to define in routes? how?

Comment: its forbidden attr error to resolve this see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835230/cant-mass-assign-a-nested-attribute/21835337#21835337

Comment: google for rails4 strongs parameters, or mass assignment, or forbidden attribute error.

Comment: see http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Comment: As u can see in the controller I already have areservation_params method as described in the other question :)

Answer (score 2):

Change this line -> @reservation = Reservation.new(params[:reservation])

To this -> @reservation = Reservation.new reservation_params

and try again ;).

Comment: This and comment the load_and_autorize for CanCan gem I can add a reservation but in the new record I obtain dinner_id null. So I think that I am smply not using the parameter

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if it wouldn't be better to have your reservation routes as a nested resource of dinners.

It seems reservations can't exist without a dinner, so I'd make that explicit like this:

`# config/routes.rb
resources :dinners do
  resources :reservations
end`

Run `rake routes` to see how this would change the routes.

You'd now have the dinner id passed along:

`# app/views/dinners/show.html.erb
<%= button_to 'Reserve this dinner', dinner_reservations_path(@dinner) %>`

The button would route to the create action because a button's default HTTP method is POST.

```
# app/controllers/reservations_controller.rb
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_dinner

  def create
    @dinner.reservations.create! user: current_user
    # would render reservations/create.html.erb
  end

  private
    def set_dinner
      @dinner = Dinner.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

This doesn't fix your immediate problem of just getting that link to work. But I think you'd be a lot better served structuring your app more like the above going forward.

Full disclosure: the person who asked this question contacted me on twitter personally, so I took some liberties in answering this question with a more general design suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the "best" approach but I think its the easiest one.

You could do something with string interpolation:

```
a href="/reservations?dinner=#{dinner.id}" Join
```

then you could get the paramter with

```
params[:dinner]
```

Comment: I changed my parameter in my controller as u said because I find u are right. Instead I cannot able to understando your link. Do u mean that I should add a manual link and add the appropiate routes.rb rules?

Comment: I think this method works but its kinda unorthodox (for me). You don't need to specify anything special in your routes because you are just appending  parameters in the URL. Although it might not be the best "Rails Way" to do it, this should work fine